# Parsing an HTML response body string to extract parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, substring

I am receiving a response body via an Ajax get request and in that body I am interested in a particular section which looks like this:

```
if (w2.isHidden() == false) {
    var counterValue = 0;
    try {
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select IFNULL( time(MAX(longestWaitingSeconds), "unixepoch") , time(0, "unixepoch")) From AvayaCMSAT_skill';
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        var text = loader.xmlDoc.responseText;
        var dataCells = text.split("<cell>");
        if (dataCells.length >= 2) {
            counterValue = dataCells[1];
            counterValue = counterValue.substring(0, counterValue.indexOf("<"));
        }
    } catch (err) {}
    var elem = document.getElementById("counter2_Value");
    elem.innerHTML = counterValue;
}

if (w5.isHidden() == false) {
    var counterValue = 0;
    try {
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select SUM(callsWaiting) From AvayaCMSAT_skill';
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        var text = loader.xmlDoc.responseText;
        var dataCells = text.split("<cell>");
        if (dataCells.length >= 2) {
            counterValue = dataCells[1];
            counterValue = counterValue.substring(0, counterValue.indexOf("<"));
        }
    } catch (err) {}
    var elem = document.getElementById("counter5_Value");
    elem.innerHTML = counterValue;
}

if (w10.isHidden() == false) {
    var counterValue = 0;
    try {
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select SUM(callsWaiting) From AvayaCMSAT_vdn';
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        var text = loader.xmlDoc.responseText;
        var dataCells = text.split("<cell>");
        if (dataCells.length >= 2) {
            counterValue = dataCells[1];
            counterValue = counterValue.substring(0, counterValue.indexOf("<"));
        }
    } catch (err) {}
    var elem = document.getElementById("counter10_Value");
    elem.innerHTML = counterValue;
}

if (w11.isHidden() == false) {
    var counterValue = 0;
    try {
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select IFNULL( time(MAX(longestWaitingSeconds), "unixepoch") , time(0, "unixepoch")) From AvayaCMSAT_vdn';
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        var text = loader.xmlDoc.responseText;
        var dataCells = text.split("<cell>");
        if (dataCells.length >= 2) {
            counterValue = dataCells[1];
            counterValue = counterValue.substring(0, counterValue.indexOf("<"));
        }
    } catch (err) {}
    var elem = document.getElementById("counter11_Value");
    elem.innerHTML = counterValue;
}

if (w1.isHidden() == false) {
    try {
        var windowDims = getWindowStatus(1, 'grid');
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select groupName as "Group Name ", groupNumber as "Group Number", callsWaiting as " Calls Waiting ", longestWaiting as "Longest Waiting Call ", acceptableServiceLevel as "Acceptable Service Level", percentInServiceLevel as " Percent Within Service Level", staffed as "Staffed Agents ", available as " Agents Available" From AvayaCMSAT_skill&windowWidth=' + windowDims[2];
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        if (loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0) {
            grid1.parse(loader.xmlDoc.responseText, 'xml');
            grid1.loadSortingFromCookie('grid1');
            grid1.loadSizeFromCookie('grid1');
        }
    } catch (err) {}
}

if (w6.isHidden() == false) {
    try {
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_chart_data&query=SELECT SUM(available) as "Staffed Agents", SUM(staffed - available) as "Unavailable Agents" from  AvayaCMSAT_skill&widgetType=pie_medium';
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        pie_medium6.clearAll();
        pie_medium6.parse(loader.xmlDoc.responseText, 'xml');
        pie_medium6.refresh();
    } catch (err) {}
}

if (w7.isHidden() == false) {
    try {
        var windowDims = getWindowStatus(7, 'grid');
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select agentName as "Agent Name", loginId as "LOGIN ID", agentExt as "Agent Extension", groupName as "Group Name", groupNumber as "Group Number", state as "Agent State", IFNULL( time((statusDuration), "unixepoch") , time(0, "unixepoch")) as"Status Duration"  From AvayaCMSAT_agent&windowWidth=' + windowDims[2];
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        if (loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0) {
            grid7.parse(loader.xmlDoc.responseText, 'xml');
            grid7.loadSortingFromCookie('grid7');
            grid7.loadSizeFromCookie('grid7');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {}
}

if (w8.isHidden() == false) {
    try {
        var windowDims = getWindowStatus(8, 'grid');
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select groupName as "Group Name", groupNumber as "Group Number", SUM(acdCalls) as " Acd Calls ", SUM(extInCalls) as " Extension In Calls ", SUM(extOutCalls) as " Extension Out Calls"  From AvayaCMSAT_agent GROUP BY groupName, groupNumber&windowWidth=' + windowDims[2];
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        if (loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0) {
            grid8.parse(loader.xmlDoc.responseText, 'xml');
            grid8.loadSortingFromCookie('grid8');
            grid8.loadSizeFromCookie('grid8');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {}
}

if (w9.isHidden() == false) {
    try {
        var windowDims = getWindowStatus(9, 'grid');
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select agentName as "Agent Name", loginId as "LOGIN ID", groupName as "Group Name", groupNumber as "Group Number", totalAcdCalls as "Total ACD Calls", avgTalkTime as "Average Talk Time", totalAfterCall as "Total After Call", totalAvailTime as "Total Available Time", totalAuxOthers as"Total Aux Others", extnCalls as "Extension Calls", avgExtnTime as "Average Extension Time", totalTimedStaff as "Total Time Staffed", totalHoldTime as "Total Hold Time"  From AvayaCMSAT_agent&windowWidth=' + windowDims[2];
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        if (loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0) {
            grid9.parse(loader.xmlDoc.responseText, 'xml');
            grid9.loadSortingFromCookie('grid9');
            grid9.loadSizeFromCookie('grid9');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {}
}

if (w3.isHidden() == false) {
    try {
        var windowDims = getWindowStatus(3, 'grid');
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select groupName as "Group Name", groupNumber as "Group Number", percentInServiceLevel as"Percent Within Service Level", totalAcdCalls as "Total Acd Calls", avgSpeedAnswer as "Average Speed Answer", abandonCalls as "Abandoned Calls", avgAbandonTalkTime as "Average Abandon Talk Time", avgTalkTime as "Average Talk Time", totalAfterCall as "Total After Call", flowIn as "Flow In", flowOut as "Flow Out", totalAuxOther as " Total Aux/Other", avgStaff as" Average Staff" From AvayaCMSAT_skill&windowWidth=' + windowDims[2];
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        if (loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0) {
            grid3.parse(loader.xmlDoc.responseText, 'xml');
            grid3.loadSortingFromCookie('grid3');
            grid3.loadSizeFromCookie('grid3');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {}
}

if (w4.isHidden() == false) {
    try {
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select 0 AS"Min", ROUND((((SUM(totalAcdCalls * percentInServiceLevel)/100)*1.0)/SUM(totalAcdCalls))*100,2) AS"Cur",100 AS "Max" From AvayaCMSAT_skill';
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        var text = loader.xmlDoc.responseText;
        var dataCells = text.split("<cell>");
        if (dataCells.length >= 3) {
            var speedoValue = dataCells[2];
            speedoValue = speedoValue.substring(0, speedoValue.indexOf("<"));
            $('#speedometer4_div').speedometer({
                percentage: speedoValue || 0
            });
        }
    }
    catch (err) {}
}

if (w12.isHidden() == false) {
    try {
        var windowDims = getWindowStatus(12, 'grid');
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select vdnName as "Vdn Name", extSkill as "Skill/Extension", num as " Vector Number", callsWaiting as "Calls Waiting", longestWaitingCall as "Longest Waiting Call", acdCalls as "Acd Calls", avgSpeedTalk as"Average Speed Talk", abandonedCalls as "Abandoned Calls", avgAbandonTime as "Average Abandon Time", avgTalkHold as "Average Talk Hold", connCalls as "Conference Calls", flowOut as "Flow Out", callBusyDisc as "Call Busy Disconnect", percentInServLevel as "Percent In Service Level"  From AvayaCMSAT_vdn WHERE meas !="none"&windowWidth=' + windowDims[2];
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        if (loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0) {
            grid12.parse(loader.xmlDoc.responseText, 'xml');
            grid12.loadSortingFromCookie('grid12');
            grid12.loadSizeFromCookie('grid12');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {}
}

if (w13.isHidden() == false) {
    try {
        var windowDims = getWindowStatus(13, 'grid');
        var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select vdnName as "Vdn Name", extSkill as "Skill/Extension", num as " Vector Number", callsOffered  as "Calls Offered", totalCalls as "Total Acd Calls", avgSpeedAnswered  as "Avg Speed Answered", totalAbandonedCalls as"Aboanded Calls", dayAvgAbandonTalk  as "AVG Abandon Talk Time", dayAvgTalkHold as "AVG Talk Hold", totalConnCalls as "Conn Calls", totalFlowOut as "Flow Out", totalCallBusyDisc as "Call Busy Disc", prctInServLevel as "Percent In Service Level"   From AvayaCMSAT_vdn WHERE meas !="none"&windowWidth=' + windowDims[2];
        var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
        if (loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0) {
            grid13.parse(loader.xmlDoc.responseText, 'xml');
            grid13.loadSortingFromCookie('grid13');
            grid13.loadSizeFromCookie('grid13');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {}
}
```

If you notice in the string above there is a repeating pattern always begining with the following:

`if (w[number].isHidden() == false){`

I am interested in the stuff that comes after that and before the final closing bracket. So for example in this case:

```
if (w2.isHidden() == false) {

 //PART TO EXTRACT
      var counterValue = 0;
      try {
          var url = site + '/user.widget?page=just_data&query=Select IFNULL(time(MAX(longestWaitingSeconds), "unixepoch") , time(0, "unixepoch"))From vayaCMSAT_skill';
          var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);
          var text = loader.xmlDoc.responseText;
          var dataCells = text.split("<cell>");
          if (dataCells.length >= 2) {
              counterValue = dataCells[1];
              counterValue = counterValue.substring(0, counterValue.indexOf("<"));
          }
      } 
      catch (err) {}
      var elem = document.getElementById("counter2_Value");
      elem.innerHTML = counterValue;
     //END PART TO EXTRACT
 }
```

As highlighted above I am intrested in extracting the string between the opening and closing {} and putting it in an array. I want to be able to do that for all if statements shown in orignal response body string.

I have looked at using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and indexOf()/substring(), e.g.:

```
var start = html.indexOf("false) {", 0) + 8;
var end = html.indexOf("if (w", start);
alert(html.substring(start, end));
```

But I have not managed to get the string between opening and closing curly brackets.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a `jsfiddle` link with this so that fix can be attempted there.

Comment: @anubhava hi i just managed to fix this problem i will be posting solution soon i ended up using string match and sub string not the most conventional way but is working for my need . thanks so much for your interest.

Comment: ok sure let me take a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328273/reducing-table-wrapper-width-for-iphone

This is the link sorry ignore the above link its older one. so sorry.

Comment: Sorry don't know much about UI coding on mobile phones.

Comment: solved it anyway thanks for taking your time. i have another question its actually regarding my ambition of learning algorithms. would you recommend any good books? actually is there way i can email u?

Comment: You can email on `anubhava[at]aol[dot]com`

Comment: hi anubhava, i have posted a new question on the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508441/updating-table-with-refresh

Comment: is it possible for you to look maybe you can help me with it. thanks

Comment: Please let me know if there is some hint even or guidance you can provide. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I do not know much about front end / UI  development. I can deal with basic Javascript but not much on HTML/CSS side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tempWidgetContent = html.match(/w\d+\.isHidden(.*)\(\) == false\)[\s\S]*?catch\(err\)\{ \}/gm);

for (var i = 0; i < tempWidgetContent.length; i++) {
    var widgetContent = tempWidgetContent[i].substring(tempWidgetContent[i].indexOf('{') + 1);
}
```

This did the trick.