# Reducing table wrapper width for iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iphone

I am making small jquery app. In it i am using [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/index) to show some information on a grid. I am having a slight issue with its display on iphone. When i display grid on my chrome or android device it is fine as you can see here i have created [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3rR6J/30/) but on iphone some of it is getting cut off. i keep messing around with css but not able to get a good looking grid. i basically wana reduce the width a little bit so i can fit it on iphone too.Can someone pelase advice.

Here is an example of what is throwing me off
I tried the following

```
#example_wrapper{


    width: 50px;

}
```

Just as an expirement to see what changes occur and i saw that the width of table got smaller in chrome but in iphone there were no changes.

This is how it looks like on iphone.[i am using iphone simulator for this but i have actual iphone too]

[image]

So if someone can please guide me it would be great.I apologize if this is a bad question as my css knowledge is limited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this, not sure if the best way but it does what i need so its good. I basically put the table in a div which has a data role equal to content and then i used the zoom in css for that div to zoom out .

```
<div data-role = "content" id="tbcontent">  

//insert table in here

</div>


#tbcontent{

zoom:80%;


}
```

Here is updated [JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/3rR6J/33/)